# How to send SMS automatically without permission notification?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, sms, ionic4, ionic-native

Our company wants to use the android phone as a server with SMS functionality, which means sending SMS automatically upon recieveing data.

I am currently using nativeSMS plugin of ionic but it always asks for manual permission every time

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the SMS without permissions then you need to use a 3rd party service.

One of the more famous suppliers are Twillo:

- https://www.twilio.com/sms

Then it can be hooked in with a simple bit of code, something like:

```
const MessagingResponse =
  require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;

app.post('/sms', (req, res) => {
  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();
  twiml.message('Thanks for signing up!');
  res.send(twiml.toString())
});
```